# Force AutoFill Save Password dialog programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, autofill

I setup Password AutoFill in my iOS 14 app. The app uses multiple tabs. `Associated Domains` are also set up. All works as expected.

I have a Test button below the user/password TextFields, which the user can press to test just entered credentials. Now, the `Save Password` dialog shows only when I change to another tab.

Is there any possibility to programmatically force the `Save Password` dialog to appear on the same tab where the user/password TextFields are located? I would like to present it to the user right after the Test button is pressed and credentials are verified to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the textfields with content type .username and .password from the view hierarchy and the save dialog will appear.